# Ionic firestore how to check document id exist in firestore or not

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add facebook login in my app. And its successfuly working but problem is every time i login with facebook it change the firestore data. Here is my code

```
   onLoginSuccess(res: FacebookLoginResponse) {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
    this.fireAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);

        this.fb.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', []).then(profile => {
        this.userData = {email: profile['email'], first_name: profile['first_name'], picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'], username: profile['name']}
        console.log(this.userData);
        console.log(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);

          let userData =  {
          email: this.userData.email,
          username: this.userData.username,
          photo: this.userData.picture,
          phone: '',
          point : '0',
          uID: this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
        };

        this.angularFirestore.collection('AppUsers').doc(this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).set(userData); //Here is the problem
        this.router.navigate(["/select"]);

      })

  });
  }
```

I need to check if there is doc already available with `this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid` so it will not add in database. IF not avaiable it will store in database.

So i need the method how can i check docID exist or not ?

Comment: Checking whether a document exists has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+check+if+document+exists. Did you try anything similar already?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can get the information if a document exists on Firestore or not.

On this question of the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332471/checking-if-a-document-exists-in-a-firestore-collection/53335711), there is all the logic for how to create a function to check a single document on the Firestore database - it's in Java, but I believe the logic should help you.

On this other post [How can i get single document from Firestore with query (I'm using Ionic 4 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801076/how-can-i-get-single-document-from-firestore-with-query-im-using-ionic-4), there is a query to return a single document as well, in case you think this one fits you better.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is "every time i login with facebook it change the firestore data" you can use "**update**" instead of "**set**".

Here is the docs about it: [Firestore Update Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#update-data)

Comment: but on first login i need to set some values for first user